# Sorting by date and number

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

How would i go about sorting a bunch of data in the format - BTC-DMMMYY-00000-K
for example:

> "instrument_name":"BTC-31DEC21-20000-P"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-24SEP21-15000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-16JUL21-40000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-30JUL21-40000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-16JUL21-25000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-16JUL21-32000-P"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-24SEP21-13000-P"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-14JUL21-37000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-23JUL21-40000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-14JUL21-38000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-24SEP21-10000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-31DEC21-44000-C"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-24SEP21-10000-P"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-24SEP21-12000-P"
> "instrument_name":"BTC-14JUL21-33000-P"

i need this to be sorted so that the dates are in order and so are the numbers next to it (strikes)
any ideas?

Comment: Please post the data sample as text, not as an image. Please explain why calling `sorted()` with proper argumemts does not work for you.

Comment: Parse into tokens using `str.split` or `re`, convert date portion to `datetime` object, convert the number part to `int`, then sort based on those components. If you show an honest attempt at doing this we can help with your implementation.

Comment: check out `sorted()` and `datetime.datetime.strptime()`.  Give a solution an attempt and people will join in to help.

Comment: Do you want it sorted ascending or descending.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the data sorted ascending and you have a list such as l

```
l = ["BTC-31DEC21-20000-P", "BTC-24SEP21-15000-C", "BTC-16JUL21-40000-C", "BTC-30JUL21-40000-C", 
"BTC-16JUL21-25000-C", "BTC-16JUL21-32000-P", "BTC-24SEP21-13000-P", "BTC-14JUL21-37000-C",
"BTC-23JUL21-40000-C","BTC-14JUL21-38000-C", "BTC-24SEP21-10000-C", "BTC-31DEC21-44000-C",
"BTC-24SEP21-10000-P", "BTC-24SEP21-12000-P", "BTC-14JUL21-33000-P"]
```

Then:

```
from datetime import datetime
sorted(l, key= lambda x: (datetime.strptime(x[4:11],'%d%b%y'), x[12:17]))
```

this will yield:

```
['BTC-14JUL21-33000-P',
 'BTC-14JUL21-37000-C',
 'BTC-14JUL21-38000-C',
 'BTC-16JUL21-25000-C',
 'BTC-16JUL21-32000-P',
 'BTC-16JUL21-40000-C',
 'BTC-23JUL21-40000-C',
 'BTC-30JUL21-40000-C',
 'BTC-24SEP21-10000-C',
 'BTC-24SEP21-10000-P',
 'BTC-24SEP21-12000-P',
 'BTC-24SEP21-13000-P',
 'BTC-24SEP21-15000-C',
 'BTC-31DEC21-20000-P',
 'BTC-31DEC21-44000-C']
```